# Use value of a field from a table dynamically in the 'where' clause of a HQL query?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Can one filter a table dynamically with a 'where' clause acting on a value of a field from another table under some other conditions such that it is made sure only one row is returned? Can I do something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stud t1 
WHERE t1.name==SELECT name FROM (
    SELECT name, row_number() over (PARTITION BY name) AS rn
    FROM stud t2) t3
WHERE t3.rn==1;
```

Of course, the above query is just a dummy one, but is filtering on where clause like above possible theoretically? If not how could one achieve such a functionality in the cases of more complex queries?

Comment: The point I wanted to question was not about how to achieve something by the query (of course, the above query is just a dummy one) but if filtering on where clause like the one above is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Query can be made like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stud t1
WHERE t1.name = (SELECT name 
                 from sometable
                 where somecondition);
```

but you need to make sure that the subquery return zero or one row. If your query *may* return more than one row, you can use `IN` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stud t1
WHERE t1.name IN (SELECT name 
                 from sometable
                 where somecondition);
```